# Export to Excel only exports a few columns - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, export

I created a survey with over 70 questions. The defualt view "All Responses" has the option to export a spreadsheet. When I created a new view with the initial view sorted, only about 7 columns are exported. The "All responses" view no longer has an export option. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you export from the overview.aspx page it should export all columns.  Maybe you're confusing the overview view with the all responses view?

Comment: Hi, The only options under Overview are View RSS Feed & Alert Me. There isn't an option under Actions to export.

Comment: If you modified the view in SPD or created a new make sure that the one you want to export is the default view.  Also what browser are you using?  Is it the 64-bit version or the 32-bit?

Comment: The view I created is the default, but that's the one that only exports some columns. I'm using IE-11. I tried Chrome but the export does not work at all. Could it be perhaps in how I created the view? Would it be better to use SPD? thank you

Comment: So if you revert the default back to overview does it then export all the columns?  I believe you can only export the default view.   I would think that if you add all the columns to your default view it should export them.  Do you have more than 7 columns added to the view you created?

Comment: That sounds correct but 2 things: 1. How do I change the default view back to "All Responses" or the "Overview"?

Comment: 2. How do I add columns to the new view I created? Sorry but obviously I'm new at this. I did Google both but can't get it to work.

Comment: I believe you can only do it in SPD.  Go to Lists and Libraries > Survey > Views.  When you click on the view you want to set as default a "Set as Default" option will be available on the top ribbon.  You can also right click on the view you want to modify and select "Edit File in Advanced Mode" and it will bring it up to edit.   If you click on the WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart tag within the code it will give you some additional options on the top of the ribbon to modify the view.  One of which is Add/Remove Columns.

Comment: Hi Nate. I don't see that option SPD. And if I right click I only get the rename option.. odd. I'll just create a new view with all columns and deal with it. Thanks!